# How to randomly change color of an object using colors in an array? Actionscript 3.0

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, random, actionscript

I have "characters" which are movieclips, placed to the stage and positioned in an array; in Actioscript 3.0.

I am trying to create an array which will contain 4 of my chosen colors, Red, Blue, Green and Grey.

My characters should change color every couple of seconds to a random color from the array.
The end goal is to have the characters clickable and if they are grey then they will be deleted and if they are one of the colors then they will not.

Can anyone help me at all please?

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively simple issue, so I'd like to see you demonstrate an attempt at doing this.  If it's not working, then post your question; otherwise, [you're asking others to program for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (or teach you, which is not the goal of StackOverflow).  In short: `research -> attempt -> fail -> research/ask -> attempt -> success`,  not: `ask > success`.

Try this:

- [Create an Array](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) with your [hexidecimal color](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/uint.html) values
- [Create a timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) which calls your listener "every couple of seconds"
- [Create the listener](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html) which [randomly selects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#random%28%29) an [index number](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#length) from your color array.
- [Apply a ColorTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html) to each of your "characters" using the random color as your value.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

For red, green and blue:

```
[0xFF0000,0x00FF00,0x0000FF][int(Math.random()*3)]
```

*user:Pixel Elephant*